# How to plot stacked & segmented bar chart over time?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data for weather conditions, over the duration of a quarter, that I need to analyse. An example of my data is below:

```
# Example dataset
Quarter <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")
Weather <- c("cloudy", "cloudy", "sunny", "cloudy", "sunny", "cloudy")
Duration <- c(16, 10, 2, 5, 15, 14)
WeatherCondData <- data.frame(Quarter, Weather, Duration, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I manually set the factor order and then plot in `ggplot2` using the following code:

```
# Make quarter a factor
WeatherCondData$Quarter <- as.factor(WeatherCondData$Quarter)
# Plot
ggplot(WeatherCondData, aes(x = Quarter, y = Duration, fill = Weather)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(WeatherCondData$Quarter))) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

However, I wish for the plot to show how long the weather conditions lasted for according to the time length of the quarter. For example, in Q2, I wish for the first part of the `geom_bar` to be red for 10 minutes, signalling cloudy conditions, then change blue for 2 minutes at the 12 minute mark (indicating it is sunny) and then back to blue or cloudy for the final 5 minutes.

In essence, I don't wish to show total durations for each condition over the quarter, but highlight when conditions change.
Is this possible using ggplot2?

Comment: if you want the colors to change, you could look into the the `gganimate` extension package of `ggplot2`. I don't know if it has this functionality but it may

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I am after a static figure. Appreciate it!

Comment: after seeing the answer below, I realized i misread your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ordering of the stacked bars to change, you need to change the grouping:

```
WeatherCondData$order <- factor(1:nrow(WeatherCondData))

ggplot(WeatherCondData, aes(x = Quarter, y = Duration, fill = Weather, group = rev(order))) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(WeatherCondData$Quarter))) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]